# Simple Java multi-threaded socket application

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, networking

I have this simple multi-threaded java socket application. Using classes Client.java

```
public class Client {

private static Socket socket;
private static boolean waitForServer = false;
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    while(true){
        socket = new Socket("localhost", ServerPortInfo.getPort());
        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new java.io.BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        while(true){
            PrintWriter.println(name + " Hello");
                waitForServer = true;

            if (waitForServer){
                BufferedReader inputBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                String inputString = null;
                while((inputString = inputBufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                    System.out.println(inputString);
                    break;
                }

            }

        }

    }
  }
}
```

And Server.java

```
public class Server {

public static ArrayList<ServerThread> connections = new ArrayList<ServerThread>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    // Init server functionality
    new Server().runServer();


}

// Implementing server functionality
public void runServer() throws IOException{

    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(ServerPortInfo.getPort());
    System.out.println("Server is running... Waiting for connections");
    while (true){
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
        // After connection handle clients in threads
        ServerThread newThread = new ServerThread(socket);
        connections.add(newThread);
        newThread.start();
    }

}
}
```

And then a Thread that handles that connection...

```
public class ServerThread extends Thread {

private static Socket socket;
public static boolean alive = true;

ServerThread(Socket socket){
    this.socket = socket;
}

public void run(){
    if (alive) {
        //DO STUFF NOW
}       

}
```

And now when I have multiple connections. It creates a different Thread for every connection. 
What should i do when a user wants to disconnect from this server?

Should i kill the thread, socket?

I tried just saying to the thread 
`alive = false;` so the run would just stop running. But this breaks other connections as well.

EDIT

ServerThread ->

```
private Socket socket;
```

And a function ->

```
void closeConnection() throws IOException{
    this.socket.close();
}
```

works like a charm.

Comment: Close the socket, and then kill the thread.

Comment: What's the purpose of this program? Homework?

Comment: `public static` variables are a recipe for disaster (as I'm sure you've just found out the hard way).  But as @cktang said, close the socket, then kill that thread (not the others).

Comment: @randnum-1 This worked and I even tried it but because of static variables as Joe C mentioned this didn't work properly. Quickly rewrote it and it works now.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Sadly we didn't learn sockets at my university so I am just educating myself to add to portfolio. So no, this not a homework.

Comment: @JoeC Thank you! Your comment pushed me to the solution. Changes added as EDIT

Comment: In that case, rather than including your solution as an edit to the question, you should post your own answer instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> public static variables are a recipe for disaster (as I'm sure you've
>       just found out the hard way). But as @cktang said, close the socket,
>       then kill that thread (not the others). -@JoeC

Changed `private static Socket socket;` to `private Socket socket;`.
Closed the socket and then Thread.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with

```
public static boolean alive = true;
private static Socket socket;
```

As it is static, it influences all your `ServerThread`'s, but each `ServerThread` (aka connected client) should have its own socket and flag indicating if it's alive or not.

Remove the `static` modifier from both attributes and 
make the flag 
`private volatile boolean alive = true;`

At first close the socket a then stop the thread (and remove it from the list).